# django 2.0.7 NoReverseMatch at /posts

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-16.04

Reverse for 'post_detail' not found. 'post_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

After Django goes to 2.0.7, I set up some url rules. It works locally at 127.0.0.1 on my computer, but not remotely on the machine (ubuntu 1604).

code:
post_list.html:

```
{% for post in posts %}
<div>
    <p>published: {{ post.published_date }}</p>
    <h1><a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>
    <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

blog.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home_page, name='home_page'),
    path('posts', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

blog.views:

```
def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})
```

mysite.urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Solved. I need to add 'blog' as my app_name in blog.url and add 'blog' as my namespace in mysite.url

Thanks guy!

In 2.0.7, I need to add an app_name (blog) in blog.url and add a namespace in mysite.url (blog). Only adding a namespace in mysite.url without adding an app_name in blog.url -> django will tell me to add an app name. Only adding an app_name in blog.url without adding a namespace in mysite.url ->  django will tell me blog is a not registered namespace. Also remember to refresh gunicorn.

Comment: perhaps you're using a namespace and need `myapp:post_detail`?

Comment: @AshishAcharya thanks so much for reminding, I wasn't using a namespace, I once used it tho but same error happen, i will experiment it now again and edit my question

Comment: The error points "at /posts", but your detail_url is "post"? Sure you are not trying to access the wrong url in your remote host?

Comment: @guillermochamorro maybe it is because I didn't refresh the gunicorn in the remote machine, and somehow the debug message is kinda outdated (I just found out this, maybe this affects too in my case). Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your app name is **blog**  so in  your blog's urls.py add

```
app_name= 'blog'
```

and in template use `{% url 'blog:post_detail' pk=post.pk %}`

Comment: thank you samiul! I also added blog namespace in mysite.url (if that need to be in the answer)